# TriggeringElement not working properly for my ajax form

Tags: forms, ajax, 10

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\demo\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Serialization\Json;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\DataCommand;

/**
 * Class Form.
 */
class PurchaseForm extends FormBase
{
    public function getFormId() {
        return 'purchase_form';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

        $product_type = get_terms_from_vocabulary('product_type', 'All');
        $parks = get_terms_from_vocabulary('theme_parks', 'All');
        $form['#attached']['library'][] = 'demo/demo-ajax-js';
        $form['product_type'] = array (
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => ('Product Type'),
            '#options' => $product_type,
            '#default_value' => $form_state->get('product_type')
        );
        $form['park'] = array (
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#title' => ('Parks'),
            '#options' => $parks,
            '#default_value' => $form_state->get('park')
        );
        $form['date'] = array (
            '#type' => 'date',
            '#title' => t('Date'),
            '#required' => TRUE,
            '#default_value' => $form_state->get('date')
        );
        $form['actions'] = [
            '#type' => 'actions',
        ];
        $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => $this->t('Get Product'),
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
        );
        if ($form_state->has('page') && $form_state->get('page') == 2) {
            return self::formPageTwo($form, $form_state);
        }
        if ($form_state->has('page') && $form_state->get('page') == 3) {
            return self::formPageThree($form, $form_state);
        }
        return $form;
    }

    public function formPageTwo(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $product_type = $form_state->get('product_type');
        $park = $form_state->get('park');
        $date = $form_state->get('date');
        $products = $form_state->get('product');        
        $form['actions']['next'] = [
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#button_type' => 'primary',
            '#value' => $this->t('Countinue'),
            '#submit' => ['::submitPageTwo'],
            '#validate' => ['::validatePageTwo'],
        ];
        foreach($products as $product) {            
            $product_node = Node::load($product->nid);
            $title = $product_node->get('title')->value;
            $product_id = $product_node->get('field_productid')->value;
            $product_type = $product_node->get('field_product_type')->target_id;
            $term_name = Term::load($product_type)->get('name')->value;
            $price = $product_node->get('field_price')->value;            
            if ($term_name == 'Dated' && empty($price)) {
                $event_id = $product_node->get('field_event_id')->value;
                $date = date_format(date_create($date),"Y-m-d");                
                $performance_response = Json::decode(\Drupal::service('vgs.performance')->get($event_id, $date, $date));
                foreach($performance_response['Answer']['Search']['PerformanceList'] as $item) {
                    $item_date = date_format(date_create($item['DateTimeFrom']),"Y-m-d");                    
                    if ($item_date == $date) {
                        foreach($item['ProductList'] as $product_data) {
                            if ($product_data['ProductId'] == $product_id) {
                                $price = $product_data['DisplayPrice'];
                                if (!empty($price)) {
                                    break;
                                }                                
                            }   
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $form[$product_id] = ['#type' => 'details', '#title' => $this->t($title), '#open' => TRUE];
            $form[$product_id]['price'] = [
                '#markup' => '<p>Starting from AED '.$price.' <small>including all taxes </small></p>',
            ];
            $form[$product_id]['minus-'. $product_id] = [
                '#type' => 'button',
                '#value' => $this->t('-'),
                '#ajax' => [
                    'callback' => [$this,'subractProduct'],
                    'event' => 'click',
                    'wrapper' => 'quantity-'. $product_id,
                    'progress' => [
                        'type' => 'throbber',
                        'message' => $this->t('Subracting Product'),
                    ],
                ],
            ];
            $form[$product_id]['quantity-'. $product_id] = [
                '#type' => 'number',                
                '#value' => 0,
                '#prefix' => '<div id="quantity-'. strtolower($product_id).'">',
                '#suffix' => '</div>',
                '#disabled' => TRUE
            ];
            $form[$product_id]['plus-'. $product_id] = [
                '#type' => 'button',
                '#value' => $this->t('+'),
                '#ajax' => [
                    'callback' => [$this,'addProduct'],
                    'event' => 'click',
                    'wrapper' => 'quantity-'. $product_id,
                    'progress' => [
                        'type' => 'throbber',
                        'message' => $this->t('Adding Product'),
                    ],
                ],
                '#description' => $product_id 
            ];   
                 
        }      
        return $form;
    }

    public function formPageThree(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }

    public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    }

    public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {  
        $product_type = $form_state->getValue('product_type');
        $park = $form_state->getValue('park');
        $date = $form_state->getValue('date');        
        $products = get_product($product_type, $park);
        $form_state->set('product_type', $product_type);
        $form_state->set('park', $park);
        $form_state->set('date', $date);
        $form_state->set('product', $products)
        ->set('page', 2)
        ->setRebuild(TRUE);
    }

    public function subractProduct(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        dpm($form_state);
        $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
        $element_name = $triggering_element['#id'];
        $pattern = '/([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/';
        $product_id = '';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $element_name, $matches)) {
            $product_id = $matches[1];            
        }
        $quantity = $form_state->getValue('quantity-'.strtoupper($product_id));
        if ($quantity > 0) {
            $quantity -= 1;
        }
        $form[$product_id]['quantity-'. $product_id]['widget'][0]['#value'] = $quantity;
        //return $form[$product_id]['quantity-'. $product_id];
        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'subCallback', [$product_id]));      
        return $response;
    }

    public function addProduct(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        dpm($form_state);
        $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
        $element_name = $triggering_element['#id'];
        \Drupal::logger('demo')->notice($element_name);
        $pattern = '/([0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12})/';
        $product_id = '';
        if (preg_match($pattern, $element_name, $matches)) {
            $product_id = end($matches);            
        }              
        \Drupal::logger('demo')->notice($product_id);
        //$quantity = $form_state->getValue('quantity-'.strtoupper($product_id));
        //$quantity += 1;
        $response = new AjaxResponse();
        $response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand(NULL, 'addCallback', [$product_id]));      
        return $response;
        //return $form[$product_id]['quantity-'. $product_id];
    }
}
```

Above code have multistep form which have list of products each products have plus and minus button with ajax call to increase and decrease quantity of product but each time a click plus or minus button it only returns last element in triggering element in ajax callback

Comment: I didn't read the full code as it's not very pleasant to read, but try to give your ajax buttons distinct `#name` attributes.